# Matrix theorem for determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let A be a square matrix.
>
> a. If a multiple of one row of A is added to another row to produce a
>   matrix B, then detB = detA.
>
> b. If two rows of A are interchanged to produce B, then detB = -detA.
>
> c. If one row of A is multiplied by k to produce B, then detB = k *
>   detA.

There were issues when copy pasting but I think I correctly replaced the special characters. My question is, would someone be able to give an example of 'a', and also can it be any two rows of A? Like what if I had a 5 x 5 matrix called A and if I perform the following interchanges, would det A = det A?

1. Replace row 1 with 3
2. Replace row 2 with 4

After those two, would I end back up with the same det?

Comment: Edit: 5 x 5, sorry

Comment: No, if you replace a row by another row, then the determinant of the matrix you obtain is zero (you have twice the same row).

Comment: Sorry I am really bad at getting what I want to say correct. So if you interchange two rows that are not multiples of each other, then the sign of the determine switches the number of times you interchange those rows, right? Assuming all interchanged rows are not multiples of one another.

Comment: If you exchange two rows, the determinant flips its sign. If, afterwards, you exchange another couple of rows, the determinant flips its sign, again, and you get what you started from ($-1\cdot-1=1$)